# Outlook clicks the nearby anchor

Tags: html, email, outlook, anchor, html-email

We send a html email to our users which has 5 anchors next to each other as in the following image:

[image]

So each star is actually an anchor with the text '✩'.

The problem is that in Outlook when user intends to click a star, the following star gets clicked instead.

For example, in the following picture, the red dot represents the area clicked:
[image]

so even if the first star was actually clicked, the link for the second star is in reality followed.

This only happens in Outlook. Gmail works well.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the html of the anchors:

```html
<a href="[first_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a><a href="[second_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a><a href="[third_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a><a href="[fourth_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a><a href="[fifth_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that different email rendering engines are interpreting the "em" value differently (although that should only affect the overall size of the star, not the link). Try to be more precise like `font-size:20px`.

There is also a UX issue here in that people on their phones pressing the star with their finger may not be able to verify which star they tapped because their finger covers the star entirely. I suggest fixing both issues by adding a space or two between each star, i.e.:

```
<a href="[first_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a> &nbsp; <a href="[second_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a> &nbsp; <a href="[third_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a> &nbsp; <a href="[fourth_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a> &nbsp; <a href="[fifth_star_link]" style="color: #FFC000; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em;">✩</a>
```

The `&nbsp;` is there so that multiple spaces don't get translated to a single space.